# Where is the blunder that White made?

Tags: engines, analysis

```
[Event "the_meayhi vs. oxygen2020"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2020-08-16"]
[White "the_meayhi"]
[Black "oxygen2020"]
[Result "1-0"]
[WhiteElo "810"]
[BlackElo "1032"]
[TimeControl "blitz"]
[Termination "the_meayhi won by resignation"]
[fen ""]

1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 c5 3. dxc5 e6 4. Bxb8 Rxb8 5. e3 Bxc5 6. Nc3 Ne7 7. Nf3 Bd6 8. Qd4 O-O 9. Bd3 a6 10. Qh4 g6 11. Ng5 h5 12. g4 Nf5 13. Bxf5 1-0
```

Despite the result of the game, te chess.com engine says that White blundered. It also says that one player was winning and blundered it away. What do those mean?

[image: engine]

Comment: It means that your opponent was once winning, but played a bad move that made you win.

Comment: @CitrusCornflakes It doesn't have to be your opponent.

Comment: Consider that the text might just be a random phrase that's shown when the engine detects a move it considers a blunder. It might not have anything to do with a specific situation in your game.

Answer (score 11):

Your last move **13.Bxf5** leaves you with a much smaller advantage than **13.gxf5**, that's what the engine is counting as a "blunder" (some of the previous moves have smaller mistakes, but none of them should be counted as "blunders")

Comment: As white blundered whats the continuation for black? For white lose some advantage

Comment: @Lifeforbetter There are no continuation for black. Black is losing no matter what, but you could've win a piece which the engine considered a "better win".

Comment: But white still winning though @David

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Black should take hte bishop. Its position is still bad, but not as much as it would have been in case of 13.gxf5

Answer (score 6):

13.Bxf5?? is a blunder because 13.gxf5 wins a piece. In other words, by playing 13.gxf5! White has a winning game. When the computer detects a big change, like a change from an even or near even game to a winning/losing game, it considers the move that caused the change to be a blunder.